# Parallax mapping hack fix

Tags: graphics, glsl, parallax

I was trying to do a parallax mapping. This is how I generate a tangents to my normal:

```
        vec4 AB  = Vert2.Position - Vert1.Position;
        vec4 AC  = Vert3.Position - Vert1.Position;
        vec2 DAB = Vert2.TextureCoord - Vert1.TextureCoord;
        vec2 DAC = Vert3.TextureCoord - Vert1.TextureCoord;

        r32 Dir = (DAC.x * DAB.y - DAC.y * DAB.x) < 0.0 ? -1.0 : 1.0;

        vec3 Tangent   = ((AC * DAC.x - AB * DAB.x) * Dir);
        vec3 Bitangent = ((AB * DAB.y - AC * DAC.y) * Dir);
```

This is how I am using data in vertex shader:

```
    vec3 Normal  = normalize(vec3(In[VertexIndex].Normal));
    vec3 Tang    = normalize(vec3(In[VertexIndex].Tangent  ));
    vec3 Bitang  = normalize(vec3(In[VertexIndex].Bitangent));
    if (dot(cross(Normal, Tang), Bitang) < 0.0)
    {
        Tang = Tang * -1.0;
    }
    TBN           = mat3(Tang, Bitang, Normal);
```

And, the biggest issue in my opinios is here(this is in fragment shader):

```
    vec3  ViewDir = normalize(TBN * (WorldUpdate.CameraPos - In.Coord).xyz);
    ViewDir *= vec3(1, -1, 1); // NOTE: this is just a hack
```

So, basically, I need to introduce this "hack" to make parallax mapping to work: before there was an issue with when I was looking up to my mesh parallax was down and when I was watching to my mesh down parallax was up. I guess there could be an issue with calculating tangents? Or something else like not correct coordinate system for TBN matrix or something? Or this is expected behavior?